# Dotnetbar StyleManager

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, styles

I am using dotnetbar metro form style manager on an MDI form with Office2010Black and OfficeMobile2014 on a child form.  But anytime the child form is called the the MDI form changes to the child form theme. Can't separate themes be used?  I need help to solve this problem. I don't want the MDI theme to change.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation in the DotNetBar StyleManager. The style is shared between all your forms.

Comment: do you know maybe why labelX or even label remain default color (fore and back) even when i change colors manually? I found i am not able to change labelX or label colors at all when using metroform or any other from dotnetbar.